# I want to Display custom Price Under price in mini-cart

Tags: magento2, module, price, custom, mini-cart

I want to display price like show in image.i want display 10% of price in mini cart under price please help me.[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can display a discount price in minicart by setting **customer group price** from admin.

```
Catalog -> Products -> Select and edit your product
```

Click on **Advanced Pricing** and set **customer group price** as attached image. It will display the discount price of products in minicart.

[image]

**Hope it will help you!**

Answer (score 0):

In Catalog > Products, edit a product and click on advanced pricing. From there, you can enter the discounted price in special price, and click save, and your original price and discounted price will show. If you want to add any slashes or make it look different you will have to style with your css or less.

Comment: Hi vikram kumar and Dylan T.Thanks for your replay.but i want to display price exactly show in my image.in minicart first display price and under price i display "Member:21.6".i create module for this in module i use event "add to cart after "  i already calculate price by 10% after add to cart.but i dont know how display "member:21.6" under original price in minicart using knockout please help i stuck there.